# 'NoneType' object is not callable' in BeautifulSoup findall()

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am very new to the wonderful world of python. The below scraper yields an object not callable error and I really do not understand why that might be. Any help very much appreciated

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("https://www.maxxim.de/lte-mini-sms1?maxxim=7hs6q1jfl95fip6qumcum4rfh4")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
nameList = bsObj.findall("h2")
for name in nameList:
     print (name.get_text())
```

Comment: You need to add the full traceback so that we can see what line gives the error. You should take the time to read [mcve].

Comment: It’s either [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) or [`findAll`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) with an upper-case `A`. – In general, “NoneType not callable” is a sign that you try to use something as a function/method that does not exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `find_all("h2")` rather than `findall("h2")`.

Comment: That’s only half correct. `find_all` works, but so does `findAll` (note the upper case `A`). `findall` on the other hand does not exist, and thus accessing `bsObj.findall` returns `None` and trying to call it `bsObj.findall()` yields the seen error. If it just returned `None`, you wouldn’t get that error but rather another one just one line later that you cannot iterate None.

Comment: I am blown away. thanks very much for your swift responses. I will also have a look at the quoted article.

Comment: @DanielP I'm glad I could help! Be sure to accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @AMagoon, your answer is incorrect as already pointed out, findAll would have worked fine, it is deprecated not removed, the problem is that there is and never was a findall.